# How do I transfer my Word 2007 autocorrect settings to Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-2010

I am running Office 2010 on Windows 7.

I would like to copy the autocorrect settings from my old PC that was running Office 2007. I copied the file MSO1033, but am unable to figure out how to import it into Word 2010.

How do I import my Word 2007 autocorrect settings into Word 2010?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  All I needed to do was replace the autocorrect file  “MSO1033” in the following network path directory : C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Office